# getLayoutParams.width vs getWidth()

Tags: android

I have the following view:

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
```

I'm implementing a timer in my project. So, the function onTick() is called every second:

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            secsPassed++;
            minsPassed = (secsPassed-1)/60;
            View dividerWhite = findViewById(R.id.dividerWhite);
            View divider = findViewById(R.id.divider);
            Log.i("divider.getWdith() = ", divider.getWidth()-secsPassed + "");
            Log.i("layout width ", divider.getLayoutParams().width + " ");
        //further code to implement a timer
```

The problem is, I'm getting -1 for `divider.getLayoutParams().width` while the value of `divider.getWidth()` is correct (i.e., the seconds remaining)

I need to dynamically change the width of the view as the seconds pass. `divider.setLayoutParams().width` is a good option to do that. But, it's not changing the layout width, which still remains -1

Answer (score 5):

`getLayoutParams().width`  returns -1 when the width is `MATCH_PARENT`. `getLayoutParams().width` can be  `FILL_PARENT` (replaced by `MATCH_PARENT`, in API Level 8) or `WRAP_CONTENT` or an exact size. But `getWidth()` always returns the width in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code.

```
int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED,
        View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
viewObject.measure(widthSpec, widthSpec);

int height = viewObject.getMeasuredHeight();
int width = viewObject.getMeasuredWidth();
```

Comment: strangely, on logging the variable `width`, I saw that it's returning 0. I'm looking for a dynamic setter of the width.

Comment: you can dynamically set width and height by layout params. Have you tried that??

Comment: yes, I tried. It should've worked, but it's not changing anything. `getLayoutParams().width` is still returning -1.

Comment: But for that you need to measure your view as you are dynamically changing your view. Try to specify View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED instead of "0" in my code.